# Compare the values in the same column and with other column values in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 3 columns `ID`, `serial_no`, `priority_no` in my table.

It may look like below

```
--------------------
ID |  Ser_No | pri_NO
--------------------
1  |  123    | 215
1  |  123    | 280
2  |  215    | 215
3  |  123    | 360
4  |  111    | 111
-------------------
```

Look at the table

We are having same `ser_no` for ID 1 and 3, and we are having same pri_no for ID 1 and 2

For ID = 1 , we are having `Pri_No` as 215 and the same 215 for `Ser_No` in ID = 2

and vice versa one record's ser_no will be in another record's `Pri_No`

The above conditions, we called it as `Family`

Now the output I need is (Not the family records)

```
--------
  ID
--------
   4
--------
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

```
    select id from table a 
    where not exists 
(select * from table where (a.Ser_No = Ser_No or a.pri_NO = pri_NO) and id!=a.id)
```

[SQL Fiddle check](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2083b/1)